# Using barweb package in Matlab

Tags: matlab, set

I am using a barweb package from MathWork: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10803-barweb--bargraph-with-error-bars-

I used following command to plot the bar chart for test:

```
barweb(barvalues, errors, [], ['20PCs';'30PCs';'41PCs';'51PCs';'73PCs'], [], 'bwXlabel', 'bwYlabel', jet, [], '   ', 2, 'axis')
```

where `barvalues` and `errors` are `5x3` matrices.

Then I find the group names `['20PCs';'30PCs';'41PCs';'51PCs';'73PCs']` is on the top of the chart, while I'd like it to be at the bottom.

I've found following line in the source code, and I believe this is the code that setting the location of the group names:

```
set(gca, 'xticklabel', groupnames, 'box', 'off', 'ticklength', [0 0], 'fontsize', 12, 'xtick',1:numgroups, 'linewidth', 2,'xgrid','off','ygrid','off');
```

I've searched for the usage of `set` command in Matlab, however, there seems no clear clue about the options for the command.

I am using Matlab R2012a. May I know how I can modify the code to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: But if you set them at the bottom you will put it on top of other text, right? However, you should post a bigger part of the code. That piece of code doesnt look like is putting the text on top. it may happen that there are 2 axis defined or something like that, but unable to tell without more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, use `get` to see what you can `set`.

The line you list doesn't say anything about location, it looks to me like this is the line you want to adjust (or just comment out, as default x-axis location is on bottom).

```
set(gca,'xaxislocation','top');
```

Setting an axis location of course also moves all the associated ticklabels with it.